# Flexbox not centering content vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

So I am attempting to use flexbox to center my name in the middle of the screen.

After looking through many upon many tutorials they say the only code I need to accomplish this, is...

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    David
  </h1>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1v4qf9h/)

If you try the code above, it only centers the box horizontally.

I found some other code that accomplishes the desired effect:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    David
  </h1>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzdq1tmk/)

but it seems a little hacky, and it just seems wrong.

Any help in what I am doing wrong would definitely be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS, block-level elements normally take 100% **width** of the parent, by default.

So, without doing anything, an `h1` will expand to cover the full width of its parent:

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; }
h1  { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    David
  </h1>
</div>
```

However, this same behavior does *not* apply to **height**. You need to specify height for a container or else it defaults to `height: auto` (height of the content).

For this reason, the content is centering horizontally but not vertically.

Horizontally, there is plenty of space to move around and there is no problem centering.

Vertically, there is no space to go because there is no extra height.

> Solution: Add height to your container.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    David
  </h1>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a1v4qf9h/1/)

References:

- [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it. Its been bothering me.